# Angular HTML equal height

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to set equal height for every single item in the list. Here as you can see in the picture some channels have companion channels(e.g CNN & HLN, BNN & CP24), they are having a different height setting as compared to the channels without any companion channels. How do I make it the same height? The second thing I am trying is to not have any channels get in the line of the alphabets(e.g the Cottage Life channel gets more to the left which gets in the line of the alphabets). Also how do I put a space between rows, I tried putting in 
 which didn't work(e.g after the A head and its channels row i need to put a blank space).

```
<div class="container col-lg-8" style="float:Left">
  <ul class="w3-ul w3-card-4" *ngFor="let head of channelDisplayHeads" style="clear:both">
    <h1 align="center" style="background-color:#0083BC;">
      <font color="white">{{ head }}</font>
    </h1>
    <ul *ngFor="let channel of channelList">
      <li class="list-group-item  logoDisplay" *ngIf="channel.channel.substr(0, 1) === head">
        <div *ngIf="channel.compChannel.compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.logo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel }}">
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.compChannel.compChannelLogo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel.compChannelName }}">
        </div>
        <ng-template #noCompChannel>
          <img class="img-rounded" src="{{ channel.logo }}" alt="{{ channel.channel }}">
        </ng-template>
        <br>
        <span class="w3-left">
          <mark>
            <font size="1">{{ channel.cbsCode }}</font>
          </mark>
        </span>
        <span class="w3-right">
          <font size="2">{{ channel.pickCode }}</font>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you specify the height of the images or the <li> tag in your css ?

Comment: I tried setting the CSS this way (.list-group-item { width: 200px; height: 200px;} ). It just messed up the whole thing. 200px/200px is the original size of all the logos in there.

Comment: Do you have any `padding/margins` if yes have you set proper `box-sizing`?

Comment: Don't have any padding or margins, tried box-sizing now, it didn't make any visible change.

Comment: I would suggest you try to setup a small example on stackblitz of your current template and styling. Otherwise it’s hard to guess where the problem is

Comment: I figured out part of the problem, if I don't use this line (<div *ngIf="channel.compChannel.compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">) I get the result the way I wanted, but I need to keep that div as I want to apply a border to the channels with the companion channels.

Comment: I was able to solve the height issue by using ng-container instead of the div tag.<div *ngIf="channel.compChannel.compChannelLogo.length !== 0; else noCompChannel">